# check all content at xml with python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

To use the open API resources, I take a service key and URL (Endpoint), and try to get whole item information with other URL requirements, item code "mdsCd", "numOfRows" and "pageNo"

So, default URL type is:

> **Endpoint**?serviceKey=**Myservicekey**&numOfRows=**number**&pageNo=**num**&mdsCd=**itemcode**

and this is my code except import code line

```
url="*endpoint*"
params={
'serviceKey':"",
'numOfRows':"",
'pageNo':"",
'mdsCd':"*aaa*"
}
response= requests.get(url,params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml-xml')
items = soup.find_all('item')

row = []
for item in items:
    row.append(item)

print(row)
```

but I can get only first item information from *row* even I check there are a lot of item that have different item code.

is this code finding the whole item?

`soup.find_all('item')`

then why row didn't show all item in Python?

```
for item in items:
    row.append(item)
```

How can I call whole item information and change that whole information to dataframe?

This is other example of response:

```
<item> <adtStaDd>20170201</adtStaDd> <chgBfMdsCd>E04420361</chgBfMdsCd> <gnlNmCd>388801BIJ</gnlNmCd> </item> <item> <adtStaDd>20191107</adtStaDd> <chgBfMdsCd>656800070</chgBfMdsCd> <gnlNmCd>237003ACH</gnlNmCd> </item>
```

but in my code, I can see only one item.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `response.text`

Comment: this is other example of response

-<item>

<adtStaDd>20170201</adtStaDd>

<chgBfMdsCd>E04420361</chgBfMdsCd>

<gnlNmCd>388801BIJ</gnlNmCd>

</item>
<item>
<adtStaDd>20191107</adtStaDd>

<chgBfMdsCd>656800070</chgBfMdsCd>

<gnlNmCd>237003ACH</gnlNmCd>
</item>

but in my code, i can see only one item

Comment: Print is not going to enumerate through the array.  Only print one item.